# TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'lnS' and 'T'

Tags: python, python-3.x

TypeError: () missing 2 required positional arguments: 'lnS' and 'T'

I tried to declare the variables 'lnS' and 'T' in different places.

The below is the code:

```
    def minimize(param):

        CF=lambda u, lnS, T:\
        cf_log_cgmy(u=u, lnS=lnS, T=Tmt, mu=r, half_etasq=param[4],\
                    C=param[0], G=param[1], M=param[2], Y=param[3])
        Call_price_CM_CF(CF, lnS)

        sum = 0
        for i in range(0,len(prices_oom)):
            a = Call_price_CF_K(np.log(strike_oom[i])) - prices_oom[i]
            sum = sum+a*a
        return sum
```

While the error is:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'lnS' and 'T'
```

Comment: What exactly does `Call_price_CM_CF` do?

Comment: I suspect the error is how you use `CF` in the `Call_price_CM_CF` function. Can you post that definition?

Comment: For easy both the original code and the error messages are saved on git

Comment: https://github.com/kficso01/CGMY/issues/1

Comment: always add code and error message as text in question, not link to external pages.

Comment: I tried but it wasn't allowed because the code was too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def psi(CF, GLOBALVJ, GLOBALALPHA, lnS, GLOBALT):

    u=GLOBALVJ-(GLOBALALPHA*1j+1j)

    denom = GLOBALALPHA**2 + GLOBALALPHA - Sigma**2 + GLOBALVJ * 2 * GLOBALALPHA * 1j + 1j * GLOBALVJ

    return CF(u)/denom
```

Here lies the problem. Inside `psi` function you are calling the `lambda CF` but **only passing one parameter**. It expects 3 as per your declaration

```py
CF=lambda u, lnS, T:\
        cf_log_cgmy(u=u, lnS=lnS, T=Tmt, mu=r, half_etasq=param[4],\
                    C=param[0], G=param[1], M=param[2], Y=param[3])
```

Comment: Thank you that was helpful.